# Can this relationship be expressed algebraically?

Tags: prime-numbers, elliptic-curves, gamma-function

$\frac{\left(x-1\right)!+1}{x}=\frac{\left(y-1\right)!+1}{y}$

When I graphed it, I noticed that it bears a resemblance with the equation (which could of course be completely coincidental):

$\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2y^2}=x^3+y^3+a\left(x+y\right)+2b$ for *a*=1 and *b*=-1.

I derived the last expression from messing around with the plane form of an elliptic curve, ($\frac{1}{y^2}=x^3+ax+b$) and then adding together the inverse function of that equation in order to mirror the symmetry of the gamma functions.

Of course I am not talking about the trivial solutions when *y*=*x* but rather the  less predictable ones, when 0<*x*<1. (Might have some relationship with the reflection formula?)

Comment: Don't really see a resemblance except that both graphs are symmetric to $y=x.$  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fwsot1g8mf

Comment: Well, if not that specific equation, then some operation on it. I am really just asking whether there is any possible algebraic relation.